# error: argument of type "void (opca_hello::)()" does not match "void* (*)(void*)"

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have written a very simple code for threading. Since I am very new to this, I have no idea about the error mentioned.

```
class opca_hello
{
 public:
void hello();
}

void opca_hello::hello()

{
printf ("hello \n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
opca_hello opca;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;
pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, opca.hello, NULL);
pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
return 0;
}
```

error: argument of type "void (opca_hello::)()" does not match "void* (*)(void*)"

Comment: Member function pointers are not the same thing as function pointers. Your member function has one parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response @chris Could you please clarify the same.I mean where exactly I need to change the code.

Comment: You need to give it a pointer to a function with no parameters.

Comment: How about making the function `static`?

Comment: Create a function that receives one parameter of type void*, call pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, that_function, &opca). From that_function call opca_hello::hello(); You will have the opca object as the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ calls to member functions need to pass a pointer to this along with the rest of the arguments.

So to use threads write code like this:

```
static void *start(void *a)
{
    opca_hello *h = reinterpret_cast<opca_hello *>(a);
    h->hello();
    return 0;
}

pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, start, &opca);
```

PS:

If you need to pass parameters to the method do something like this (for example):

struct threadDetails {
   opca_hello *obj;
   int p;
};

```
static void *start(void *a)
{
    struct threadDetails *td = reinterpret_cast<struct threadDetails *>(a);
    td->obj->hello(td->p);
    delete td;
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
struct threadDetails *td = new struct threadDetails;
td->obj = &opca;
td->p = 500;
pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, start, td);
```

Comment: Got an error::Main.cpp:4: error: âvoid*â is not a pointer-to-object type.
If later I change my code to call a function inside hello, then static can't be used. Right?